# grails - URI rewrite faculty in URL Mapping

Tags: grails

[Section 6.4.1](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#mappingToControllersAndActions) of the Grails manual indicates:

"To rewrite one URI onto another explicit URI (rather than a controller/action pair) do something like this:

```
 "/hello"(uri: "/hello.dispatch")
```

Rewriting specific URIs is often useful when integrating with other frameworks."

I was hoping to use this faculty to map directly onto an html file, e.g.

```
   "/test"(uri: "/test.html")
```

but it didn't work.  Can you please clarify / expand on what the URI faculty is for (e.g. what is "hello.dispatch" typically)?   Any working example of how to use this URI faculty would be great.

---

Also, if you do know a way to map a URI onto an html file type (and not a GSP/JSP), please let me know.  The view faculty appears to only map onto GSPs/JSPs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying should work. Make sure that you put `test.html` at `/path/to/project/web-app/test.html`